# Difference between MongoDb Index and SQL Index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database, nosql

Is there a difference between two index concepts? MongoDB is a type of "NoSQL" implementation and its data can be scattered among nodes. Does this feature make index concept differ from that of relational DB?

I mean, in a relational DB, an index is applied on each column and one corresponding index table is created.

With a NoSQL DB index, does each node has its own index table for each collection it stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexes are more or less the [same in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/#behavior-of-indexes) as SQL databases you're familiar with.

When a collection is sharded (partioned) across multiple nodes, each node only indexes the portion of data that is stored on it.